# Weird output with bash script for backing up directories

Tags: bash, if-statement

I wrote a Bash script for backing up a directory's content into a `.tar` file. I intent on updating the script into something more organize, portable, and shareable. However, I cannot for the life of me understand a bug in my code, where the output in a occasion shouldn't change the `$OUTDIR` to the same path as `$INDIR`.

It happens whenever `-d` is appended to the file command's parameters, which should display the strings used in the actual gist of the script, the `tar` command, to define it's own parameters. I've rewritten that part of my code twice and I can't understand why the output differs everytime.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script will only back up an accessible directories
# Any directories that require 'sudo' will not work.

if [[ -z $1 ]]; then                    # This specifically
    INDIR=$(pwd); debug=false;          # is the part where 
elif [[ $1 == '-d' ]]; then             # the 'debug' variable 
    debug=true;                        # is tampering with 
    if [[ -z $2 ]]; then INDIR=$(pwd); # the output somehow.
    else INDIR=$2; fi
else 
    INDIR=$1; debug=false; fi

if [[ -z $2 ]]; then
    OUTDIR=$INDIR
elif [[ '$2' = '$INDIR' ]]; then
    if [[ -z $3 ]]; then OUTDIR=$INDIR;
    else OUTDIR=$3; fi
else
    OUTDIR=$2; fi

FILENAME=bak_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M).tar
FILEPATH=$OUTDIR'/'$FILENAME
LOGPATH=$OUTDIR'/bak.log'

if [[ "$debug" = true ]]; then
    echo "Input directory:  "$INDIR
    echo "Output directory: "$OUTDIR
    echo "Output file path: "$FILEPATH
    echo "Log file path:        "$LOGPATH
else
    tar --exclude=$FILEPATH --exclude=$LOGPATH \
    -zcvf $FILEPATH $INDIR > $LOGPATH
fi
```

This is the output

```
gnomop@GnomoPC:~$ bakdir -d
Input directory:    /home/gnomop
Output directory:   /home/gnomop
Output file path:   /home/gnomop/bak_20170804_2123.tar
Log file path:      /home/gnomop/bak.log
gnomop@GnomoPC:~$ bakdir -d /home/other
Input directory:    /home/other
Output directory:   /home/other
Output file path:   /home/other/bak_20170804_2124.tar
Log file path:      /home/other/bak.log
gnomop@GnomoPC:~$ bakdir -d /home/other /home/other/bak
Input directory:    /home/other
Output directory:   /home/other  
Output file path:   /home/other/bak_20170804_2124.tar
Log file path:      /home/other/bak.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single quotes aren't allowing tha variables to expand.

You need to correct this line:

```
elif [[ '$2' = '$INDIR' ]];
```

in this way:

```
elif [[ "$2" = "$INDIR" ]];
```

Answer (score 0):

@whoan is right about the immediate problem, but I'd suggest a complete rewrite of the argument parsing logic to make it simpler. For options like `-d`, the best thing to do is check for it (/them), then remove them from the argument list with `shift`, and then set the positional parameters. For example, this means that `INDIR` will either be `$1` (if that's set) or `$(pwd)`; no complication about it sometimes being `$2`.

Also, it's best to use lowercase (or mixed case) variable names in shell scripts, because there are a large number of all-caps variables with special meanings, and if you accidentally use one of those... bad things can happen. (The classic example is trying to use `$PATH` to something other than the list of directories to search for commands, at which point you start getting a lot of "command not found" errors.) Also, it's best to put double-quotes around all variable references; there are places where they're not necessary, but there are a lot of places where leaving them off can cause weird bugs. Finally, there's a shell shortcut for using an alternate string if a variable isn't set: `indir="${1:-$(pwd)}"` will set `$indir` to `$1` if that's set and not blank, and to `$(pwd)` otherwise.

```
if [ "$1" = "-d" ]; then
    debug=true
    shift    # remove -d from the argument list, to simplify parsing the positional parameters
else
    debug=false
fi

indir="${1:-$(pwd)}"
outdir="${2:-$indir}"
```